# How do I short this scala code?

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization

I am a Scala newbie. I tried turkish citizenship number validation algorithm.

How do I implement and optimize this scala code?

You can find my java version this link https://gist.github.com/hasanozgan/5601623

```
trait TurkishCitizenshipNumberValidator {

  private def odd(tckn: String): Int = {
    tckn.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) {
      (total, x) =>
        x match {
          case i if ((i._2 % 2 == 0 && i._2 < 10)) => ((i._1.asDigit) + total)
          case _ => total
        }
    }
  }

  private def even(tckn: String): Int = {
    tckn.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) {
      (total, x) =>
        x match {
          case i if ((i._2 % 2 == 1) && i._2 < 9) => ((i._1.asDigit) + total)
          case _ => total
        }
    }
  }

  private def total(tckn: String): Int = {
    tckn.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) {
      (total, x) =>
        x match {
          case i if (i._2 < 10) => ((i._1.asDigit) + total)
          case _ => total
        }
    }
  }

  def turkishCitizenshipNumberValidator(t: String): Boolean = {
    val digit10 = total(t) % 10
    val digit9 = ((odd(t) * 7) - even(t)) % 10

    ((t(9).asDigit == digit9) && t(10).asDigit == digit10)
  }
}

object test extends TurkishCitizenshipNumberValidator {
  // http://tckimliknouretici.appspot.com/
    turkishCitizenshipNumberValidator("29419391592")
                                                  //> res0: Boolean = true
}
```

Comment: Although @0__'s suggestion is good, you can step back even further and ask what you're doing. You're partitioning the indices by their index parity and then doing something to the partitioned values. I'd advise looking at the `partition` method (or `groupBy`, which is a more general version of the same thing) and working from there. The whole thing can get extremely succinct and will be more readable than your fairly low-level code. It's much easier to understand if you say "sum the even digits and sum the odd digits and then ..."

Comment: Yet another approach is to think of `foo.grouped(2).toList.transpose.map(_.sum)`.

Comment: This might be more on-topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it both compact and clear, and need basic input validation (right length, things are digits), I'd

```
def turkishCitizenshipNumberValidator(t: String): Boolean = {
  if (t.length != 11 || !t.forall(_.isDigit)) false
  else {
    val n = t.map(_.asDigit)
    val evens = n.grouped(2).take(5).map(_(0)).sum
    val odds = n.grouped(2).take(4).map(_(1)).sum
    n(10) == (n.take(10).sum % 10) && n(9) == ((odds*7 - evens) % 10)
  }
}
```

The keys here are using `grouped` to pull the string apart in even-odd pairs, and mapping digits to numbers at the start so it's not too much of a headache to work with them.

---

Edit: If you'd rather obfuscate your code, try this!

```
def tCNV(t: String) = t.map(_.asDigit).foldLeft(Seq(0,0,0)){ (v,n) => v(2) match {
  case 10 => Seq(v(0)-n,v(1),0); case 9 => Seq(v(0)+n,v(1)-n,10)
  case i => Seq(v(0)+n, v(1)+n*(7*(i%2)+(i%2-1)), i+1)
}}.take(2).map(_%10).forall(_ == 0)
```

Comment: Second method is very cleaver. `n` is the current digit, `v(0)` is calculating `digit10`, `v(1)` is calculating `digit9` (with a formula that multiplies odds by seven and subtract evens on the fly), `v(2)` is the counter. By the time that the counter hits 9, it subtracts the ninth digit from `v(1)`, and by the time the counter hits 10, it subtracts the tenth digit from `v(0)`... Later it applies a `mod(10)` on both and verify if they are equal to zero. This works because `n(9) == v(1) % 10 → v(1) - n(9) % 10 == 0` and  `n(10) == v(0) % 10 → v(0) - n(10) % 10 == 0`.

Comment: Also this should be pretty fast: one iteration to convert the digits (could be avoid with `view`), one to do the math. Shorting the `Seq` from three to two elements, `mod(10)` over it and a last iteration over two elements to check the condition. @Rex, one question though. Why `Seq` and not `Tuple3`? It would surely obfuscate the code a little further ;).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly - Because then for it to be a one-liner I'd have to match instead of take/map/forall.  Too ugly, and repeats the `%10`.  Also, it's not particularly fast because it's boxed.  The fast way is a while loop with integer accumulators (but a similar strategy).

Comment: As I posted in my comment to the original question, I think `.transpose` on the grouped output would give you the goodness of succinctness without really obfuscating it (as) much.

Comment: @MyseriousDan - But you need to take 5 from one and 4 from the other, and at that point it's not really any more succinct since you need another variable, etc..

Comment: Ah, my bad, I assumed Scala's `transpose` allowed ragged input like Haskell's does, but it throws an exception instead, which makes the whole thing a lot uglier :) the basic observation was just that the index munging isn't fundamental (and rarely is) and the sum of everything is just the sum of the two parity-aware sums. Checking `n(10)` and `n(9)` separately is the same as checking them together as a `Seq` generated from `splitAt` on the original string. Perhaps I'll throw together what I'd do in Haskell "for the lulz", since I think it'd be quite readable yet succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have three times the same body with a minor difference. So you should factor out that body as one auxiliary method with an additional function argument to test the index:

```
private def check(tckn: String)(pred: Int => Boolean): Int = {
  tckn.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) {
    (total, x) =>
      x match {
        case i if pred(i._2) => ((i._1.asDigit) + total)
        case _ => total
      }
  }
}

private def odd(tckn: String): Int = check(tckn)(i => i % 2 == 0 && i < 10)
```

etc.

---

Secondly, you can simplify the `check` code a bit, by extracting the tuple of character and index, and you don't need a pattern match if you just have one guard, as a simple `if` will do (more a matter of taste, though).

```
private def check(tckn: String)(pred: Int => Boolean): Int =
  tckn.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) { case (total, (char, idx)) =>
    if (pred(idx)) char.asDigit + total else total
  }
```

Comment: Hint: `.zipWithIndex.filter.sum`

Comment: Also the check `< 10`, that's just an initial `take(10)`. You can partition into even and odd with `partition`. Etc., there are many more ways to make this better.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
def turkishCitizenshipNumberValidator(t: String): Boolean = {
  val digits = t.init.map(_.asDigit)
  val digit10 = digits.sum % 10
  val (odd, even) = digits.zipWithIndex.partition(_._2 % 2 == 0)
  val digit9 = ((odd.map(_._1).sum * 7) - even.init.map(_._1).sum) % 10

  ((t(9).asDigit == digit9) && t(10).asDigit == digit10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With problems like this where a string needs to be deconstructed and then processed it is sometimes easier to zip the pattern to the string and then use the usual collection methods to do the processing.

In this specific case, the pattern is a simple even-odd pattern, so zipping the Citizenship number to a string of alternating characters, one-two's, is the place to start, like so...

```
def turkishCitizenshipNumberValidator( digits:String ) = {

  val pattern = Stream.continually("12".toStream).flatten  // An odd & evens pattern

  val d = digits.
          filter(_.isDigit).        // Filter out the non-digits 
          map(_.asDigit).           // Convert Char to Int
          zip(pattern)              // Zip to a repeating string of one-two's, for odd & evens

  val odds = d.take(9).filter( _._2 == '1' ).map( _._1 ).sum 
  val evens = d.take(8).filter( _._2 == '2' ).map( _._1 ).sum
  val total = d.take(10).map( _._1 ).sum 

  d.size == 11 && (odds * 7 - evens) % 10 == d(9)._1 && total % 10 == d(10)._1
}

turkishCitizenshipNumberValidator("29419391592")
```